# Twitter Bootstrap Button / Tabs Tapping Ipad Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, twitter-bootstrap, ipad

I have a webpage for displaying 3 panels(panel_freegame, panel_1game & panel_2game) based on the click of 3 buttons(Free Game, 1 Game at time & 2 game at a time).

I have written jQuery code to display them accordingly, and its working well and fine in all web browsers, except in ipad if I continuously tap/click the buttons, 2 buttons get in selected state. So the tapping is not smooth and instant, this is issue with buttons, navtabs, nav pills.

Please suggest me with a suitable fix.

Thank you.

Comment: can you share your code here?

Comment: Please post your code otherwise we can't see what you've already tried

Comment: Here is the link for my code - https://codeshare.io/SYvb1

Comment: Did anyone figure out the issue ?